# USB Space reading

Tags: usb, storage

I am using my Apple Mac book to take film from a external hard drive and drag it across to a 64GB USB. The total space I have left on the USB is 31GB the film is only 16GB but I keep getting the message the film is too big. Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the error and the disk space?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your drive is formatted in FAT32, which allows maximum file sizes of 4GB.

If you type `diskutil list` in the terminal, you should quite quickly see what format the disk uses.